# Plotting 2D satellite profile data in 3D over earth projection in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, satellite-image

I am attempting to do something similar to this:

[sample ozone profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSMcK.png)

Not necessarily over an orthographic projection - a cube over a map would suffice.

I'm able to plot the PolyCollection object produced by matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor, but cannot figure out if there's an accepted way of plotting the profile over an arbitrary lat/lon path.

The only thing I can think of right now is continuing to use pcolor() to get the face colors, then just modifying the vertices for each Poly object.

Comment: What does your code look like? Please post it inside your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a 3D projection, then you may use the `plot_surface`. It essentially draws a 2D array where the 3D coordinates of each vertex is given.

You might get some ideas by looking at this: [Creating intersecting images in matplotlib with imshow or other function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287861/creating-intersecting-images-in-matplotlib-with-imshow-or-other-function/25295272#25295272)

The `matplotlib` solution there is essentially the same as using `pcolor`, but the 3D arithmetics is carried out by `matplotlib`. The suggestion to use `mayavi` is also something worth conisdering, as `matplotlib` is not at its strongest with 3D projected raster data.