# Plotting an imshow() image in 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, matplotlib-3d

How to plot a `imshow()` image in 3d axes? I was trying with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295272/4920782). In that post, the surface plot looks same as `imshow()` plot but actually they are not. To demonstrate, here I took different data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# create a 21 x 21 vertex mesh
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,21), np.linspace(0,1,21))

# create vertices for a rotated mesh (3D rotation matrix)
X =  xx 
Y =  yy
Z =  10*np.ones(X.shape)

# create some dummy data (20 x 20) for the image
data = np.cos(xx) * np.cos(xx) + np.sin(yy) * np.sin(yy)

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()

# show the reference image
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.BrBG, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=[0,1,0,1])

# show the 3D rotated projection
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.BrBG(data), shade=False)
```

Here are my plots:

[image: http://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~raj/imshow_plot_surface.png]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your error in the 3D vs 2D surface colour is due to data normalisation in the surface colours. If you normalise the data passed to `plot_surface` facecolor with,  `facecolors=plt.cm.BrBG(data/data.max())` the results are closer to what you'd expect.

If you simply want a slice normal to a coordinate axis, instead of  using `imshow`, you could use `contourf`, which is supported in 3D as of matplotlib 1.1.0,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# create a 21 x 21 vertex mesh
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,21), np.linspace(0,1,21))

# create vertices for a rotated mesh (3D rotation matrix)
X =  xx 
Y =  yy
Z =  10*np.ones(X.shape)

# create some dummy data (20 x 20) for the image
data = np.cos(xx) * np.cos(xx) + np.sin(yy) * np.sin(yy)

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()

# show the reference image
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.BrBG, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=[0,1,0,1])

# show the 3D rotated projection
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
cset = ax2.contourf(X, Y, data, 100, zdir='z', offset=0.5, cmap=cm.BrBG)

ax2.set_zlim((0.,1.))

plt.colorbar(cset)
plt.show()
```

This code results in this image:

[image: result]

Although this won't work for a slice at an arbitrary position in 3D where the imshow [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287861/creating-intersecting-images-in-matplotlib-with-imshow-or-other-function/25295272#25295272) is better.

Comment: `facecolors=plt.cm.BrBG(data/data.max())` trick solved my problem. The `contourf` gives same plot.

Comment: The advantage of filled contour `contourf` is that you have full control over colour limits like `vmin` and `vmax`, you can display the colorbar with the correct range and you can specify the smoothing/number of levels (100 in the example above). The `imshow` mapped onto a surface is a great idea but it's a hack whereas contourf is actually supported in 3D.

Comment: @Ed Smith using `contourf`, `Z` is not used -- technically the image *is* plot in 3D, but failing to provide full control over its position, this solution is not really useful.

Comment: @user1735003, The OP's issue was with normalisation here I think (sorry, been a while). As `Z` just sets the position, you could control this with `offset, e.g. `offset=10.` (and set `ax2.set_zlim((9.4,10.6))`).

Comment: @Ed Smith To have a genuine 3D solution you should be able to place the image anywhere in space, as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287861/creating-intersecting-images-in-matplotlib-with-imshow-or-other-function/25295272#25295272) provided in the original post. This solution limits the image to being normal to the `z` axis IIUC.

Comment: `contour` plots a contour and not an image per `imshow`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [plotImage](https://github.com/mstranne/py_matplotlib_helper/blob/main/src/3D_pose_plot.py)  function here. You can place the image anywhere and rotate however you need it. Also to not create huge surfaces, you can also downscale the image. Hope this helps!
[image]