# I want to plot a 2d surface on a 3d basemap in python

Tags: 3d, matplotlib-basemap

I have a vertical data set with height levels and latitude as dimensions. I would like to plot it on a basemap vertically [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHnyw.jpg). My data is like this [vertical surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf4GC.jpg)

Data can be acquired from my git https://github.com/kmmrao/3dplot_with_2d_surface.git

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by combining methods from:

- https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/bars3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-bars3d-py
- [Plotting a imshow() image in 3d in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464117/plotting-a-imshow-image-in-3d-in-matplotlib)

> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import numpy as np
>
> ```
> fig = plt.figure()
> ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
> yticks = [3, 2, 1, 0]
> X,Z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,21), np.linspace(0,1,21))
> data = np.cos(X) * np.cos(X) + np.sin(Z) * np.sin(Z)
> for c, k in zip(colors, yticks):
>     Y =  k*np.ones(X.shape)
>     ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.BrBG(data/data.max()), shade=False)
> ax.set_xlabel('X')
> ax.set_ylabel('Y')
> ax.set_zlabel('Z')
> ax.set_yticks(yticks)
> plt.show()
> ```

Comment: Can you please help me out?