# How can I install mayavi on Windows for python 3 via conda?

Tags: python, windows, conda, mayavi

I have a python 3 virtual environment managed by conda on Windows. I want to install the mayavi package via

```
conda install mayavi
```

but it says it requires python 2.7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your luck with a `mayavi` package available on other channels, by [searching on the Anaconda website](https://anaconda.org/search?q=access%3Apublic%20platform%3Awin-64%20mayavi).

As of today, the one maintained on the `conda-forge` channel is compatible with python 3.5 and 3.6. To install it,

```
conda install -c conda-forge mayavi
```

If `mayavi` fails with an

```
ImportError: Could not import backend for traits
```

it may be because qt is not installed or that qt5 is installed -- in that case it needs to be downgraded

```
conda install pyqt=4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you can try:

If you have Visual Studio installed, and Python Native Development Tools installed.

In Anaconda3, you can get VTK7.1.x from clinicalgraphics

```
conda install -c clinicalgraphics vtk
```

Open up the VS20xx x64 Native Command Prompt, setting up PATH for python properly:
e.g.

```
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Anaconda3
```

Then install mayavi using pip from source.

```
pip install mayavi
```

It compiles successfully with VS2017 and Python 3.6 in windows 10.