# Plotting 2D panels to form 3D boxes in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot several 2D panels in order to form three boxes using Python but am having some trouble. 
What I have right now uses Matplotlib, but I'm open to using something else if it's easier.

Basically this is a MWE of what I got:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

L = 400
dx=2*4
dz=1*4

# create the figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(16, 8), subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d', aspect="equal"))

ax=axes

for i in range(3):
    x, y, z = np.arange(dx/2, L, dx)+i*5*L/4, np.arange(dx/2, L, dx), np.arange(-240, dz, dz)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    A=np.random.rand(*xx.shape)

    #----
    # Plot surface
    X = xx
    Y = yy
    Z = np.zeros_like(xx)

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.viridis(A), shade=False)
    #----

    #----
    # Plot x-z cross-section
    xx, zz = np.meshgrid(x, z)
    Y=np.zeros_like(xx)
    X=xx
    Z=zz

    B=np.random.rand(*xx.shape)*2
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.viridis(B), shade=False)
    #----

    #----
    # Plot x-z cross-section
    yy, zz = np.meshgrid(y, z)
    X=np.zeros_like(xx)+xx.max()
    Y=yy
    Z=zz

    B=np.random.rand(*xx.shape)/2
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.viridis(B), shade=False)
    #----

#ax.set_axis_off()
# make the panes transparent
ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
# make the grid lines transparent
ax.xaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] =  (1,1,1,0)
ax.yaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] =  (1,1,1,0)
ax.zaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] =  (1,1,1,0)
```

This code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295272/4506929) and it produces this:

[image]

Two things are wrong with this picture:

- the aspect ratio is off
- the boxes are always too small compared to the size of the picture

I think I can somewhat take care of the aspect ratio problem with some hacks, even though it would be nice to deal with it in a proper way. However, I have tried like crazy to zoom in the picture without success.

Again, I'm willing to use something other than pyplot, although, since I'm planing on using `xarray`, it would be nice to have something that blends in nicely with it.

Comment: For 3d plotting at best stop using Matplotlib immediately. It is not made for that. [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) is the best tool for that. If you are on Windows get the packages from [Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mayavi).

Comment: @Joe I'm on Linux. I'd be glad to use Mayavi, but honestly I couldn't find a comprehensive example on that. I've never used it before and I have to do this plot soon, so I can't spend some days completely learning a new tool before using it

Comment: Don't worry. Mayavi is very easy to use and there are a lot of examples. About installation on Linux, read [this](https://pypi.org/project/mayavi/) or [this](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html). Are you using a distribution like Anaconda or Enthought?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I've read those. But I always run into issues installing Mayavi. Currently, this is my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51880687/4506929